# How to upload multiple images in a single browse option in webform file component field?

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I have added file field in webform content and tried to browse multiple images and upload it @once, But webform file field only supports only one image while clicking single browse. Tried Installing [Webform Multiple File Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multifile) still its only supporting one image per browse.

Is there any way to upload multiple images in a single browse option and upload it.Thanks in advance.